# Depend on a project from another Gradle script

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I have the following folder structure:

```
projects
    build.gradle
    core/
    samples/
        sample1/
            build.gradle
            core/
            desktop/
            ios/
            html/
            android/
```

The `core` project is a Java library while `sample1` is a Libgdx application that wants to depend on `core`.

The outermost build file is responsible for the `core` project as well as another project (not listed).

The problem is that the Libgdx application also contains a `core` project, which hosts all the shared game logic. This is the template generated by the Libgdx project setup tool.

How could I work around this in Gradle without renaming any of the projects?

Answer (score 0):

In the root projects level, you need to add 'settings.gradle' which have something like:

```
rootProject.name = 'projects'

include ':core'
project(':core').projectDir = "$rootDir/core" as File

include ':samples:sample1:core'
project(':samples:sample1:core').projectDir = "$rootDir/samples/sample1/core" as File

include ':samples:sample1:desktop'
project(':samples:sample1:desktop').projectDir = "$rootDir/samples/sample1/desktop" as File
```

...

in your project(desktop for example) build.gradle you can add dependencies like:

```
compile project(':core')
compile project(':samples:sample1:core')
```

ps: Libgdx is nice

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without polluting the root folder? I'd have to add many entries, one per project of each sample... Maybe I should rename the Libgdx core project...

Comment: in each sample, you can add similar settings.gradle but use relative path for :core, for example in sample1 use: project(':core').projectDir = "../../core" as File. also, you can use any other name instead of :core as long as it point to that directory